# How to import and use a module with one line

Tags: python, python-import

I have this code that loads the natural gas storage numbers from the internet.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
print(int(str(urlopen("http://ir.eia.gov/ngs/wngsr.txt").read()).split("\\n")[4].split(" ")[2]))
```

How could I do this in one line? More specifically, I was wondering how I could get rid of the import line and do something like this:

```
print(int(str(urllib.request.urlopen("http://ir.eia.gov/ngs/wngsr.txt").read()).split("\\n")[4].split(" ")[2]))
```

(I changed the `urlopen` call to `urllib.request.urlopen`. It would be sort of like Java, if you use the fully qualified name, you don't need an import statement.)

Comment: You always need the import

Comment: Check out the dunder__import__ builtin. But this is a bad baaaad idea.

Comment: Python imports do not simply create a reference in the local namespace to that class or function (like Java), they also run the module's `__init__.py` code to set up the environment to support the module's functions and classes. That's why they always need to be imported before being used.

Comment: Also, I'd like to ask myself a question 'why' would I want to do that? Unless one line is super fast or something - that isn't the case in your particular example!

Comment: @jwilner Lol I get that, but when I used __import__, I couldn't call functions from it. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @TheTromboneWilly: If that's the *real* problem, then that is a better question. Otherwise this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @AaronD: I found it useful when you try to run some short python code as part of a shell script for example. Being able to pass the entire code as a single line to the python interpreter makes it a lot neater

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You always need the import, however you can still use semi-colons to separate statements:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen; print(int(str(urllib.request.urlopen("http://ir.eia.gov/ngs/wngsr.txt").read()).split("\\n")[4].split(" ")[2]))
#             note the semi-colon ^
```

Comment: I'm not saying I'd ever use it in real life, I just wanted to know if it was possible. Thanks

Comment: Why would you do that? To run commands in shell. Here's a oneliner I use almost every day to count the total number of csv records in a file that accepts line breaks inside strings:  cat *.csv | python -c "import csv; import sys; print(sum(1 for i in csv.reader(sys.stdin)))"

Answer (score 18):

When trying out the suggestion by Zizouz212, I found this works

```
print(int(str(__import__('urllib').request.urlopen("http://ir.eia.gov/ngs/wngsr.txt").read()).split("\\n")[4].split(" ")[2]))
```

Comment: LOL I forgot about this question. This is a good idea, but I think you need to add the `fromlist` parameter to import the submodules. So the `__import__` will look this this: `__import__('urllib', fromlist=['request'])`

Answer (score -1):

E.g. Use like this:

```bash
python -c 'import cyrtranslit; print(cyrtranslit.to_latin("бла-бла-бла", "ru"))'
```

Or like this:

```bash
python -c 'import cyrtranslit,sys; print(cyrtranslit.to_latin(sys.argv[1], "ru"))' 'бла-бла-бла'
```

Result: `bla-bla-bla`

Or like this:

```bash
python -c 'import sys; from urllib import parse; print(parse.unquote(sys.argv[1]))' 'bla%20bla%20bla'
```

Result: `bla bla bla`

Comment: I previously downvoted this, but this does actually work. I was using the incorrect `-m` flag. This works perfectly for me and should be the accepted answer.